# Substring Extraction exercise

Tags: c, algorithm

Given 2 strings, write a function that returns the position of String B that matches String A if String A is a substring of String B. Otherwise return -1. 
Example:

```
strA = "ello"
strB = "Hello_World"
Your function should return 1.

strA = "blah"
strB = "blha"
Your function should return -1.
```

Comment: As I see only questions made by genius are accepted here!
Why everybody is so rude with newbies?

Comment: Don't get other people to do your homework. You won't learn what you are supposed to learn if you don't do it yourself.

Comment: Because this isn't HomeworkOverflow. You don't have to be a genius, but you do have to not be trying to cheat on homework, and put some effort into solving the problem yourself

Comment: backslash17, the problem with this style of question is that it is obviously some sort of exercise which the asker seems to expect us to solve for him.  Mind you, there is nothing wrong with asking for help, but it would be prudent to show some own effort.

Comment: If he is cheating is his problem not ours, remember that one question can solve problems for a lot of pleople not only the asker!!!!!

Comment: +1. StackOverflow was open to anyone last time I checked, and there is at least one post about "should i answer homework questions". It´s a valid question, non argumentative, etc etc...

Comment: No one said, Never help people with homework.  I just prefer people are honest, and preferably try to do it themselves first.

Comment: I'm just here for the rep points :PPP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute force version:

```
int strpos(char* a, char* b) {
  int n1, n2, i, j;
  n1 = strlen(a);
  n2 = strlen(b);
  for (i = 0; i < n1-n2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
      if (a[i+j] != b[j]) break;
      else if (j+1 == n2) return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

More effective algorithms: [Wikipedia: String searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching)

Comment: If you're going to use string.h anyway (or really even if you're not), why so verbose?  Also, by doing strlen ahead of time, you lose most of your benefit from breaking out of the loop.

Comment: Just to show how it can be done.

Comment: Yes, but as I said, that's a naive implementation, because of the strlen among other things.

Answer (score 3):

Is this homework?  Anyway, look the [string.h documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/) and you should find what you need without much trouble.  You will need to write a very thin wrapper over one of the functions.  Or, of course, you can just write it all yourself.

EDIT: Well, someone else gave a answer, so here's my attempt.

```
#include <string.h>

ssize_t str_index(const char *strA, const char *strB)
{
    const char *result;
    return (result = strstr(strB, strA)) ? (result - strB) : -1;  
}
```

The only tricks are that the parameter order is reversed from strstr, you're returning an ssize_t instead of char *, and the failure code is thus -1.

Comment: Just wanted to say you are trusting strstr() to have a "nice" implementation, when it could be a morbid disaster.

Comment: And that size_t is unsigned. ssize_t should be used.

Comment: Good catch on ssize_t.  Out of curiousity, does anyone know what (if any) warning level catches that with gcc?  -Wall -Wextra does not.

And yes, I'm deliberately trusting strstr because I have no reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string.h>

int search(char* a, char* b) {
    char* pos;
    pos = strstr(b, a);
    if(pos == 0) return -1;
    return (int)(pos-b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds almost exactly like a homework problem. In the strange case that it is not a homework problem, the C library function strstr returns a pointer to the first occurrence of a string inside another (or null if it is not there). From there, it is trivial to determine the index using pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Trying learning about strstr. Its available in string.h
There is **NEVER** a reason to code something already available in the standard library.
Unless ofcourse, its a homework question :)

Comment: Its always not homework.At times people try to implement the function so they can get the working of the function in a better way

Comment: @fahad : fair enough but the way OP posed his question smelled like homework